# link directly to GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

In a GSP, is it possible to create a direct link to another GSP? I know I can use:

```
<g:createLink controller="user" action="foo"/>
```

and in UserController define the foo action to just show the corresponding GSP

```
class UserController {
    def foo = {}
}
```

But is there any way I can achieve the same result without having to create the empty `foo` action?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [createLink tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) is geared for use with controller actions and won't do what you want it to outside of the url attribute.

You can always get to a gsp by directly: `/user/foo.gsp` with a combination of the [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) and [resource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) tags.

```
<g:link url="${resource(dir:'user', file:'foo.gsp')}">user/foo.gsp</g:link>
```

Othewise you can create a URL Mapping that maps a request directly to a view.

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/user/foo"(view:"user/foo")
    }
}
```

Using Grails 1.2 you can create a [named URL Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings) that maps directly to a view:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        name userFoo: "/user/foo"(view:"user/foo")
    }
}
```

and then use it with the link tag:

```
<link:userFoo>User Foo</link:userFoo>
```

or

```
<g:link mapping="userFoo">User Foo</g:link>
```

Answer (score 13):

There's a uri attribute that's [undocumented](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) , but you can see it in the [source](http://github.com/grails/grails/blob/master/grails/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ApplicationTagLib.groovy):

```
<a href="${createLink(uri:'/path/page.gsp')}">link</a>
```

HTH

Comment: Hey Dave, what should the path be? I tried "/views/p.gsp " and "grails-app/views/p.gsp" Neither worked.

Comment: Remove the /views/ out of your path, just do p# instead of p.gsp and it should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 2.x, this is not possible.  The ability to link directly to a .gsp was a security flaw that could be used to avoid the `@Secured` annotation.  The URL mapping method does still work though as seen in @Colin Harrington's answer.

See: [GRAILS-7542: Views are accessible via a URL pattern](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/4664)