# Link directly to another gsp

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I want to link to another gsp file.

I tried:

```
<li>
 <a href="/private/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

However, this results in `http://localhost:8080/private/dashboard` which is basically not where I want to go.

Any recommendations what I could change to link to my `dashboard.gsp`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link directly to GSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170386/link-directly-to-gsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a mapping to `UrlMappings.groovy` to make your link point to a GSP view:

```
"/private/dashboard" (view:"/private/dashboard")
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `<g:link>`-Tag to create a Link to a controller action.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html